# "En" in "Sa voix restait si calme et naturelle que mon exclamation m’en parut d’autant plus ridiculement emphatique"

Tags: expressions, pronoms

This question is on the following sentence, from chapter 7 of *La porte étroite* by André Gide.

> Sa voix restait si calme et naturelle que mon exclamation m’**en** parut d’autant plus ridiculement emphatique.

**QUESTION**

I am trying to account for *en* and have come up with the following ideas.  Please let me know if they are right.  Where they are wrong, please tell me what I should have thought instead.

1. A *d’autant plus* + adverb construction may be completed with either a *pour*-phrase or a *que*-clause supplying a cause, reason or occasion.  (This would be rather like *so much the more* + adverb completing with a *for*, *now that* or *as*.)
2. *En* in the Gide sentence results from (represents or means) *pour + le*.  From this I should draw the lesson that *en* may unpack into *pour* + something, and not always *de* + something.
3. *Le*, or the 'thing' in *en*, in this case would be the whole preceding clause, i.e. *Sa voix restait si calme et naturelle*.

Comment: It's 3. It's not easy to find documentation about that specific use, but the others are right, it's 3.

Comment: Tossing in my agreement for that analysis. In fact, you sometimes find an "en" used in a very loose way to refer to more or less all that went before, even when it's hard to pinpoint the exact phrase that the pronoun is linking as the cause of / contributor to sense of the verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your third option seems all right.

> Sa voix restait si calme et naturelle que mon exclamation m’**en** parut d’autant plus ridiculement emphatique.

Without changing the whole structure, you could reconstruct a *de*-headed complement:

> Sa voix restait si calme et naturelle que mon exclamation me parut **de ce fait** d’autant plus ridiculement emphatique.

But of course, you could also reverse subordination, getting a completely different structure for approximately the same meaning:

> Mon exclamation me parut d’autant plus ridiculement emphatique **que** *sa voix restait si calme et naturelle*.

Comment: Thank you. I particularly appreciate being told that a noun (such as *ce fait*) would connect with *de* (not *pour* or *que*).

Answer (score 1):

1. I can see *d'autant plus + adverb + que*, but not *d'autant plus + adverb + pour*. Could you give an example with *pour* that we could look at?
2. I don't think a priori that this *en* has to do with a *pour-phrase* or *que-clause*. I think it only stands in for *Sa voix restait si calme et naturelle*.
3. Yes.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot find anything with *pour* in it. (I thought I did yesterday, but it was a misreading of a different usage of *pour*.) Besides GAM PUB seems to have told us that a noun phrase (supplying a cause etc.) would be headed with *de* as in *de ce fait*.